# What is a good way to store arbitrary schedule data?

Tags: time, cron, schedule

I am working on a project where the objective is to keep track of whether a client has uploaded data within their expected time-window or not. These windows can occur daily, weekly, bi-weekly, bi-monthly, quarterly... etc. I'm currently using the CRON syntax to describe these schedules which kind-of works, but it falls short in some scenarios, for example the bi-weekly one.

I was wondering if there is some industry standard way to efficiently describe and store schedules that I don't know of. I tried to educate myself via Google, but when I put the word schedule into the mix, it always assumes I'm trying to schedule some task, but I only want to calculate dates based on these schedule definitions and compare the incoming file dates with them.

Thank you